# How can I use rowSums with conditions to return binary value?

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame with a column for summed data.  What is the most efficient way to return a binary 0 or 1 in a new column if any value in columns a, b, or c are NOT zero?  `rowSums` is fine for a total, but I also need a simple indicator if anything differs from a value.

```
tt <- data.frame(a=c(0,-5,0,0), b=c(0,5,10,0), c=c(-5,0,0,0))
tt[, ncol(tt)+1] <- rowSums(tt)
```

This yields:

```
> tt
   a  b  c V4
1  0  0 -5 -5
2 -5  5  0  0
3  0 10 10 20
4  0  0  0  0
```

The fourth column is a simple sum of the data in the first three columns.  How can I add a fifth column that returns a binary 1/0 value if any value differs from a criteria set on the first three columns?

For example, is there a simple way to return a 1 if any of a, b, or c are NOT 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
as.numeric(rowSums(tt != 0) > 0)
# [1] 1 1 1 0
```

`tt != 0` gives us a logical matrix telling us where there are values not equal to zero in `tt`.

When the sum of each row is greater than zero (`rowSums(tt != 0) > 0)`, we know that at least one value in that row is not zero.

Then we convert the result to numeric (`as.numeric(.)`) and we've got a binary vector result.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Reduce`

```
+(Reduce(`|`, lapply(tt, `!=`, 0)))
#[1] 1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One could also use the good old `apply` loop:

```
+apply(tt != 0, 1, any)
#[1] 1 1 1 0
```

The argument `tt != 0` is a logical matrix with entries stating whether the value is different from zero. Then `apply()` with margin `1` is used for a row-wise operation to check if `any` of the entries is `true`. The prefix `+` converts the logical output into numeric 0 or 1. It is a shorthand version of `as.numeric()`.